# Can "confusion" be plural?

Tags: grammatical-number

Can **confusion** be spelled as a plural, as in:

> The child must sort out **confusions** of voice-to-print while reading.

I thought ***confusion*** was "global" enough to mean "more than one."

Can it be plural?

Comment: Sounds perfectly natural to me.

Comment: The word is used as a mass (uncountable) noun most of the time, but has a countable noun usage. [Confusion](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/confusion): The mistaking of one person or thing for another: [COUNT NOUN]: **most of the errors are reasonable confusions between similar words**.

Comment: **Questions that can be answered using [commonly-available references](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available) are off-topic**. Please make sure that you take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) for additional guidance.

Comment: Thank you, Rathony!  This was for an educator, and i thought perhaps it was a "normal usage" for teachers, etc.  I have never seen it as a plural, so I thought I'd better ask.  I appreciate the input!   ;-)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/confusion), yes.

> *Most of the errors are reasonable confusions between similar words or sequences of words.*

Comment: Oxford Dictionaries Online (ODO) is not the same as the Oxford English Dictionary (OED), which is subscription-only. But +1 anyway.

Comment: Clearly I should have checked my OED.   :-)   Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Many words which denote abstractions can be used both as mass nouns and as count nouns, meaning "an instance of the abstraction". "Confusion" is just one example.

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate all who weighed in.  Just because I had never encountered that word didn't mean it wasn't legit.   :-)